# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{-f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)}{(g(x))^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[image]

In this problem I can write the integrand as $$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{-f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)}{(g(x))^2}}dx+\int_{0}^{1}{(f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x))}dx$$.The second integral easily can be written as $[f(x)g(x)]_0^1$.But how do I handle the first integrand?

Comment: The first integrand is $(\frac{f}{g})'$

Comment: @HasanSaad Got it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You may try to calculate $(f/g)'$

Comment: Oh damn xD! I did'nt see that ! Thanks.